# Uploading digital products with size more than 5MB in nopCommerce results "Upload failed" error

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, product, nopcommerce

I have a shop for digital products that is built with nopCommerce (a famous eccommerce software).
But uploading digital products with size more than 5MB results "Upload failed" erro, what is the solution?

Comment: please check in errror log log, there is full description of error, after that you know why is throw an error or put that error stack strace here so anyone can understand and provide solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the NopCommerce setting **catalogsettings.fileuploadmaximumsizebytes**.

Second you can also try edit the web.config as folows

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> <!--50MB-->
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default max default file size is 4MB in ASP.Net. Look for this setting in your web.config.

```
<httpRuntime   
    maxRequestLength = "number" 
/>
```

Change where I have the word number to your desired size in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update 2 items in the web.config.  Update the value to whatever you'd like your max to be.

1.Add this within the system.webServer tags:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

2.Update the httpRuntime tag:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" enableVersionHeader="false" maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
```